# Are "car prices" and "the price of a car" synonymous?

Tags: meaning

Obviously, "the price of a car" can also mean the price of a car in general, so I am wondering if "car prices" and "the price of a car" are basically synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some overlap, but *car prices* carries more of a connotation of representing the full range of prices on the market. In some contexts, they are pretty much equivalent:

> The effect of the exchange rate on the price of a car/car prices

But in others, they are not:

> He has an amazing knowledge of car prices.

Answer (score 1):

The price of a car is not car prices.

**Car prices are the prices for cars in a market**. **"Cars prices" is plural and general**. Car prices=the prices of cars, with an s.

**The price of the car in the parking lot is $10,000.**
**The price of a car in my area is not cheap.**

A plural noun and a singular noun are not the same thing.